# What happens when we type "rails" or "ruby" from terminal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line-interface

Complete beginner question, but I was wondering what happens when I type things like `rails g draft:resource ...` into the terminal. I know the end result, but I don't understand why it works.

In other words, what is it exactly that I'm doing? Am I calling a rails program? (if so, where is this program and why can I call it from anywhere without CD?)

Very similarly, why can I do `ruby -version` too? What changes in my computer after installing Ruby and Rails such that my terminal understands these commands now? And what is being executed exactly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> was wondering what happens when I type things like rails g draft:resource ... into the terminal

Calling `rails` is calling a command line interface (CLI) exposed by the open source software package `rails` you installed from https://guides.rubygems.org/ likely via the command-line tool called `gem` (i.e. `gem install rails`).

`g` which is an alias for the word `generate` is a subcommand of this CLI that generates some code based on the following parameters (`draft:resource`, etc.). It's just another part of the `rails` software package. You can check out the source code here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/commands.rb#L6.

> why can I do ruby -version too?

At some point, `ruby` was installed (usually by rvm or rbenv). From your terminal, you can understand what program your command is calling by typing `command -v` or `which` prior to your command, and digging deeper from there.

```
$ which ruby
/Users/avinashmoondra/.rbenv/shims/ruby
$ which rails
/Users/avinashmoondra/.rbenv/shims/rails
```

E.g. these are the equivalent:

```
$ /Users/avinashmoondra/.rbenv/shims/ruby -v
ruby 2.6.4p104 (2019-08-28 revision 67798) [x86_64-darwin18]
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.6.4p104 (2019-08-28 revision 67798) [x86_64-darwin18]
```

Ruby (and SQLite3) is required to install Rails, see: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#installing-rails. If you are using [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv), a ruby version manager, you'll get similar results as above.

> What changes in my computer after installing Ruby and Rails such that my terminal understands these commands now?

It's explained in rbenv documentation, here: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#how-it-works. Summary: *At a high level, rbenv intercepts Ruby commands using shim executables injected into your PATH, determines which Ruby version has been specified by your application, and passes your commands along to the correct Ruby installation.*

Comment: Great answer! Still have a couple of questions if you don't mind:
1) What is the CLI exposed by rails? Is this a kind of shortcut for a shell script that runs a program and passing arguments to it?
2) When we install Ruby, a bunch of files are installed. When we type "ruby -v", what is being called? An .exe, a script, ...?

Comment: (1) The CLI exposed by Rails is Ruby program that is built on Thor, a gem (another Ruby program). http://whatisthor.com/ details how it exposes an executable, and does CLI option parsing. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/command/base.rb#L13 is the entry point for Rails specifically. (2) typing `cat /Users/avinashmoondra/.rbenv/shims/ruby` will print out the contents of that file -- in my environment, that's a bash script that's executable. that eventually calls `exec "/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.2/libexec/rbenv" exec "$program" "$@"`. Layers and layers of software!